# Suitable ssd for Asus ROG STRIX B450 F GAMING motherboard

Tags: motherboard, ssd

My son's pc has this motherboard: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B450-F-GAMING

The manual says that storage support is:
[image]
https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/ROG_STRIX_B450_F_GAMING/E14401_ROG_STRIX_B450-F_GAMING_UM_WEB.pdf

We have one Kingston A1000 240GB M.2 SSD M.2 2280, PCIe 3.0 x2, NVMe, 3D TLC already installed.

I'm looking at this drive Kingston A2000 M.2 2280 NVMe PCIe Gen 3.0 x 4. Would it work with this setup?

https://www.kingston.com/en/ssd/a2000-nvme-pcie-ssd

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work. Lengthwise, it will fit in either slot.

As visible from the product pictures on the A2000 NVMe PCIe SSD, there are 5 pins on the smaller side of the key; that identifies it as an M key connector, just like the motherboard requires.

Do note the notes though:

> When the M.2_1 Socket 3 is operating in SATA or PCIE mode, SATA6G_5/6 ports will be disabled.

and

> *4 When the M.2_2 is occupied by M.2 device, PCIe x16_1 will run at x8 mode.

Especially the second point -. installing an NVMe SSD in the second slot - may create a throughput bottleneck for the graphics card.

Comment: So would it be better to use a normal 2.5" SSD, e.g. https://www.kingston.com/en/ssd/a400-solid-state-drive, since as a gaming computer graphics speed is probably more important than disk throughput? Or should we replace the current 240GB M.2 with a 1TB and reinstall the machine?

Comment: I don't think it'll be much of a disadvantage for the video card - at least for current games and "normal" GPUs:
https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/2488-pci-e-3-x8-vs-x16-performance-impact-on-gpus

SSD performance wise, I found good SATA drives to be sufficient for loading games from. Only the OS and smaller programs seem to really benefits from being put on an NVMe drive. (Source: 500 GB Samsung 970 EVO NVMe, 1 TB SATA SSD, 4 TB SATA HDD on a B350 AM4 mainboard)